# authenticated access to redfish on an ASMB9-iKVM

Tags: ipmi, bmc, asus, redfish

I have a workstation with an `ASUS Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE WIFI` motherboard, that comes with an `ASMB9-iKVM` controller (Firmware version: 1.17.0)
Which works nicely.

Recently I've discovered, that the the iKVM controller announces itself via SSDP, which I would like to change.
The webinterface does not reveal any settings regarding SSDP; however, the manual (https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/server/accessory/ASMB9/E16160_ASMB9-iKVM_UM_V3_PRINT.pdf §4.3.27) suggests, that I can access the SSDP settings via redfish. cool.

I can access `https://machine.example.com/redfish/v1/` and get a JSON-view of the serviceRoot. However, accessing this does not require any authentication, which makes it easy.

According to the docs, I must access the `Managers` section (that is: `https://machine.example.com/redfish/v1/Managers/Self/NetworkProtocol`) but I seem to be unable to get the right username/password for authentication, so I am denied access:

with curl:

```
$ curl -k --fail-with-body \
     https://machine.example.com/redfish
{
  "v1": "/redfish/v1/"
}

$ curl -k --fail-with-body \
     https://machine.example.com/redfish/v1 \
| jq ".Managers"
{
  "@odata.id": "/redfish/v1/Managers"
}


$ curl -k --fail-with-body \
     https://USER:PASS@machine.example.com/redfish/v1/Managers/Self/NetworkProtocol \
| jq
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401
{
  "error": {
    "@Message.ExtendedInfo": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Message.v1_0_8.Message",
        "Message": "While attempting to establish a connection to /redfish/v1/Managers/Self/NetworkProtocol, the service was denied access.",
        "MessageArgs": [
          "/redfish/v1/Managers/Self/NetworkProtocol"
        ],
        "MessageId": "Security.1.0.AccessDenied",
        "Resolution": "Attempt to ensure that the URI is correct and that the service has the appropriate credentials.",
        "Severity": "Critical"
      }
    ],
    "code": "Security.1.0.AccessDenied",
    "message": "While attempting to establish a connection to /redfish/v1/Managers/Self/NetworkProtocol, the service was denied access."
  }
}

$ curl -k --fail-with-body \
     -X POST 'https://machine.example.com/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{ "UserName": "USER", "Password": "PASS" }'
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401
{
  "error": {
    "@Message.ExtendedInfo": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Message.v1_0_8.Message",
        "Message": "While attempting to establish a connection to /redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions, the service was denied access.",
        "MessageArgs": [
          "/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions"
        ],
        "MessageId": "Security.1.0.AccessDenied",
        "Resolution": "Attempt to ensure that the URI is correct and that the service has the appropriate credentials.",
        "Severity": "Critical"
      }
    ],
    "code": "Security.1.0.AccessDenied",
    "message": "While attempting to establish a connection to /redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions, the service was denied access."
  }
}
```

with `redfishtool` (https://github.com/DMTF/Redfishtool):

```
$ redfishtool -S Always -u USER -p PASS -r machine.example.com versions
{
    "v1": "/redfish/v1/"
}

$ redfishtool -S Always -u USER -p PASS -r machine.example.com -vvv SessionService login
#REQUEST: Transport:SendRecv:    GET https://machine.example.com/redfish/v1/
#REQUEST: Transport:SendRecv:    POST https://machine.example.com/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions
   redfishtool: Transport: Response Error: status_code: 401 -- Unauthorized
   redfishtool: Error: Session Login Failed: Post to Sessions collection failed


$ redfishtool -S Always -u USER -p PASS -r machine.example.com -vvv Managers
#REQUEST: Transport:SendRecv:    GET https://machine.example.com/redfish/v1/
#REQUEST: Transport:SendRecv:    GET https://machine.example.com/redfish/v1/Managers
   redfishtool: Transport: Response Error: status_code: 401 -- Unauthorized
# Main: Error: rc=5
```

I've tried to create accounts in webinterface with varying privilege levels ("Administrator", "Operator", "User", "OEM" and even "None") and all access domains ("KVM", "VMedia", "SNMP"), making sure the username/password *has* or *has not* special chars and what not, but no matter what I do, I cannot authenticate.

So what am I doing wrong?
How can I authenticate against redfish on my board?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the documentation you have. Referencing the following guide, you may want to try creating a "session", and getting a token.

https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP2060_1.0.0.pdf

**4.3 Sessions**

Redfish sessions allow a user to exchange a username and password for a session token, and the session token is
used in susbsequent requests. This is a more optimal approach when performing a multiple operations so that the
username and password only need to be verified by the service on the initial session creation request.

To create a session, perform a POST operation on the
`/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions` URI:

```xml
curl -k -D - \
-X POST 'https://<REDFISH-HOST>/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{ "UserName": "<USERNAME>", "Password": "<PASSWORD>" }'
```

The response from the service, if successful, will contain the session ID and session token in the Location and X-
Auth-Token response headers respectively. These values need to be saved for future operations with the session.

In subsequent requests to the service, provide the X-Auth-Token request header with the session token received in
the response from the session creation. The following example shows a request to the URI `/redfish/v1/Chassis/1U`
with the X-Auth-Token header provided:

```xml
curl -k 'https://<REDFISH-HOST>/redfish/v1/Chassis/1U' \
-H 'X-Auth-Token: <SESSION-TOKEN>'
```

Comment: good point (just shows how little in understand about redfish); however, while my `curl` invocation might be botched, i think the `redfishtool` (https://github.com/DMTF/Redfishtool) should properly handle authentication (i'm updating my Q to now include my login attempts). in any case, i have not been able to get a session-token with your example either...

Comment: @umläute: you can also try base64 encoding the credentials, and specifying the string with `-H Authorization: Basic <Base64-encoded credentials>`.

Comment: That said, probably need to confirm what, if any, authentication types are enabled. I believe it supports LDAP, PAM, and others.

Comment: thanks. of course (in the meantime) i've tried the Basic-Authorization, to no avail. afaiu my problem is exactly that i do not know where the redfish server on the BMC gets its users from. i *can* setup local users via the webinterface (and i *think* this is what is used for PAM), but haven't found a setup that would allow me to authenticate with redfish yet. configuring LDAP seems a bit like an overkill, but i will eventually try this.